# uninstall init.d update-rc.d remove

Tags: init.d

I installed an init.d script with this command:

```
sudo update-rc.d mongodb defaults 98 02
```

I want to uninstall it, so I'm planning on running:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f mongodb remove
```

I'm concerned about the start and stop conditions in the installation command.
Will running the remove cause the start and stop conditions to be removed also?

Are there any implications that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Will running the remove cause the start and stop conditions to be removed also?

It will remove any instance of your script from the system, meaning, any link in `/etc/rc*runlevel*.d` to the `mongodb` script in your `/etc/init.d`.

> Are there any implications that I should be aware of?

If some other script depends of `mongodb` to start/stop it will fail.

[Check the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-rc.d.8.html#contenttoc4) for a complete description.

Comment: Hello, I realise it is a bit late to respond to this answer, but I wonder why https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto says on deactivating init scripts: 'Do not use the update-rc.d command for this purpose! It is only used in package installation scripts, and not designed for this kind of runlevel management.'What the problems with using it like that?

Comment: @user2520938 because they are saying that one should use upstart management instead, but in this case, the user installed a script using sysvinit helpers, so it has to use the sysvinit to remove it.